# In a loop over an array, add an element to the array

Tags: bash, array, for

I have a problem with for loop in bash. For example:
I have an array `("etc" "bin" "var")`.
And I iterate on this array. But in the loop I would like append some value to the array. E.g.

```
array=("etc" "bin" "var")
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
echo $i
done
```

This displays `etc` `bin` `var` (of course on separate lines).
And if I append after `do` like that:

```
array=("etc" "bin" "var")
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
array+=("sbin")
echo $i
done
```

I want: `etc` `bin` `var` `sbin` (of course on separate lines).

This is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: Altering the thing you're iterating over is always a risky proposition.  It's often a good time to step back and consider if there's another approach that might make sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *will* append "sbin" 3 times as it should, but it won't iterate over the newly added "sbin"s in the same loop.

After the 2nd example:

```
echo "${array[@]}"
#=> etc bin var sbin sbin sbin
```

Comment: Yes, thats right, but I need add to the same loop :)

Comment: Use two `for` loops then. First peform your additions, then loop over the result.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to append sbin in the loop though. Appending it just once kind of makes more sense: `array+=(sbin); for i in ...`

Comment: becouse in for loop I must check if some file which is copying by this for loop has some content..

Answer (score 5):

```
set etc bin var
while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
do    [ "$1" = bin ] &&
      set "$@" sbin
      printf %s\\n "$1"
shift;done
```

That will iterate over your list, tack `sbin` onto the end of said list conditionally, and include `sbin` in the iterable content.